# DELETE values in MySQL that are not null

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got a condition already for a MySQL delete query, but I'm also trying to ensure that it isn't executed if the value is null.

I.e.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id (some quality here) GROUP BY id2
```

I'm trying to see what else I would have to do to add that the value of id2 should not be null. Is there a way to do this? It doesn't seem like there's a standard way to do that with the is null, at least not with the "Group by" part.

I don't want to delete all rows that are not null. I just want to make sure I'm not deleting any rows that ARE null for id2.

I.e. if id2 isn't filled for any given row (regardless of anything else), that row should NOT be deleted.

Comment: Are you trying to insure that id is not null or id2 is not null?

Comment: `GROUP BY` is used for consolidating result sets, so in the context of a `DELETE` it's meaningless. Don't you mean `WHERE id2 IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: id2 is not null.

id2 is a calculated value that won't be assigned for every row.

Comment: what is the calculation for ID2?

Comment: Why does that matter? It's calculated in program code based on the row information. However, there are so many rows in the database table that the calculations and assignment aren't done all at once, and I want this delete function to be able to be run without deleting all the entries without a value yet.

Answer (score 4):

Just add another condition with `AND` and `IS NOT NULL`:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id (some quality here) AND id2 IS NOT NULL
```

Note that you do not need to group rows here. In fact, [you can't use `GROUP BY` in a `DELETE` statement, per the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html):

```
Single-table syntax:
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```